# Deserializing XML where each object has a list of objects

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on a WP7 app which gets and updates data on a web server. If any updates need a response, I get a list of errors that needs to be dealt with, and a list of possible choices for each error. The issue I'm having is assigning each object its appropriate list of choices. As of now I get a list of errors, and another list of all possible choices for all errors. I'd like the error object to contain the list of only its options so I can handle that.

So here's an example response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <response_error_dialogs>
        <error_dialog_list>
            <error_dialog_choice>
                <error_dialog_id>1301</error_dialog_id>
                <error_dialog_message>You have changed the phone number.  Select which phone number to make the primary contact number.</error_dialog_message>
                <error_dialog_title>Phone Number Changed</error_dialog_title>
                <error_dialog_is_set>false</error_dialog_is_set>
                <error_dialog_choice_option_list>
                    <error_dialog_choice_option>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_id>1</error_dialog_choice_option_id>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_title>Home</error_dialog_choice_option_title>
                    </error_dialog_choice_option>
                    <error_dialog_choice_option>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_id>2</error_dialog_choice_option_id>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_title>Mobile</error_dialog_choice_option_title>
                    </error_dialog_choice_option>
                    <error_dialog_choice_option>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_id>3</error_dialog_choice_option_id>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_title>Work</error_dialog_choice_option_title>
                    </error_dialog_choice_option>
                </error_dialog_choice_option_list>
            </error_dialog_choice>
            <error_dialog_choice>
                <error_dialog_id>1303</error_dialog_id>
                <error_dialog_message>You have changed the account email address.  Would you like this to be the new default email?</error_dialog_message>
                <error_dialog_title>Email Address Changed</error_dialog_title>
                <error_dialog_is_set>false</error_dialog_is_set>
                <error_dialog_choice_option_list>
                    <error_dialog_choice_option>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_id>1</error_dialog_choice_option_id>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_title>No</error_dialog_choice_option_title>
                    </error_dialog_choice_option>
                    <error_dialog_choice_option>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_id>2</error_dialog_choice_option_id>
                        <error_dialog_choice_option_title>Yes</error_dialog_choice_option_title>
                    </error_dialog_choice_option>
                </error_dialog_choice_option_list>
            </error_dialog_choice>
        </error_dialog_list>
    </response_error_dialogs>
</response>
```

And here's the classes used:

```
public class ErrorDialog
{
    XElement self;

    public ErrorDialog() { }

    public ErrorDialog(XElement errorDialog)
    {
        self = errorDialog;
    }

    public int errorDialogId
    {
        get { return (int)(self.Element("error_dialog_id")); }
    }
    public string errorDialogMessage
    {
        get { return (string)(self.Element("error_dialog_message")); }
    }
    public string errorDialogTitle
    {
        get { return (string)(self.Element("error_dialog_title")); }
    }
    public bool errorDialogIsSet
    {
        get { return (bool)(self.Element("error_dialog_is_set")); }
    }
    public List<ErrorDialogChoice> errorDialogChoice
    {
        get { return (List<ErrorDialogChoice>)(errorDialogChoice); }
    }
    public int errorDialogSelectedOption
    {
        get { return (int)(self.Element("error_dialog_selected_option")); }
    }
}

class ErrorDialogChoice
{
    XElement self;

    public ErrorDialogChoice() { }

    public ErrorDialogChoice(XElement errorDialogChoice)
    {
        self = errorDialogChoice;
    }

    public int errorDialogChoiceOptionId
    {
        get { return (int)(self.Element("error_dialog_choice_option_id")); }
    }
    public string errorDialogChoiceOptionTitle
    {
        get { return (string)(self.Element("error_dialog_choice_option_title")); }
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm parsing it:

```
XElement response = XElement.Parse(data);  

ErrorDialog[] dialogs = response
    .Element("response_error_dialogs")
    .Element("error_dialog_list")
    .Elements("error_dialog_choice")
    .Select(e => new ErrorDialog(e))
    .ToArray();

ErrorDialogChoice[] edChoices = response
    .Element("response_error_dialogs")
    .Element("error_dialog_list")
    .Element("error_dialog_choice")
    .Element("error_dialog_choice_option_list")
    .Elements("error_dialog_choice_option")
    .Select(e => new ErrorDialogChoice(e))
    .ToArray();
```

So with this example, the first `error_dialog_choice` object will have a `List` containing 3 `error_dialog_choice_option` objects, the second has the two `error_dialog_choice_option` objects, and any more that may come back. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Might it be easier to use XmlSerializer? You could even use xsd.exe to generate the types from sample XML...

Comment: Agree with Marc use the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XML serialization to achieve this much easier:

```
var reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
var result = (Response) ser.Deserialize(reader);
```

Using these class definitions.

```
[XmlType("response")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("response_error_dialogs")]
    public ErrorDialog ErrorDialog;
}

[XmlType("response_error_dialogs")]
public class ErrorDialog
{
    [XmlArray("error_dialog_list")]
    public List<ChoiceErrorDialog> ChoiceList;
}

[XmlType("error_dialog_choice")]
public class ChoiceErrorDialog
{
    [XmlElement("error_dialog_id")]
    public int Id;

    [XmlElement("error_dialog_message")]
    public string Message;

    [XmlElement("error_dialog_title")]
    public string Title;

    [XmlElement("error_dialog_is_set")]
    public bool IsSet;

    [XmlArray("error_dialog_choice_option_list")]
    public List<Option> OptionList;
}

[XmlType("error_dialog_choice_option")]
public class Option
{
    [XmlElement("error_dialog_choice_option_id")]
    public int Id;

    [XmlElement("error_dialog_choice_option_title")]
    public string Title;
}
```

I am guessing there can be more types of error dialogs, and `<error_dialog_choice>` is just one of the possible types. In this case you could use subclassing, and list the subclasses with `XmlArrayItem` attributes.

---

You could also *generate* the class definitions with `xsd.exe` or `svcutil.exe`, from an `.xsd` or `.wsdl` file. `xsd.exe` can even infer the schema from a sample `.xml` file.

```
xsd.exe /?
svcutil.exe /?
```

Comment: No you beat me by 1 minute! Very comprehensive answer though. :) I didn't go into all the detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `XmlSerializer` built into the framework. Use attributes to map out the xml equivalent of your classes and their properties.

Example:

```
[XmlElement("Txn")]
public List<Transaction> Items { get; set; }
```

You can use the XSD.exe to generate an XSD and then generate C# code for your XSD. Use Visual Studio Command Prompt with a sample response.xml file. Eg:

c:>xsd response.xml

c:>xsd response.xsd /c /edb